# Receiving HTTP Bad Request when calling a .NET Webservice using SOAP only from Android

Tags: android, sockets, soap, web, service

**EDIT**: For anyone using the same method as I am (building a Soap.java file and using sockets), stop! Use the [kSoap-Android](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) library as it automates pretty much everything and has little to no bugs like this.

I'm creating an android application where you can quicly check your timeroster for the classes in the next week. To do this, I use 2 servers:

- The server that hosts the timerosters for every student in HTML form
  (I do not manage this server)
- The server that hosts my webservice (which I manage). It's a .NET webservice and is finished.

### [image: Visualisation:]

The android device connects to the Webservice-server and sends the function "login" with parameters "username": "usernameX" and "password": "passwordX".

The webservice-server then retrieves the login-page from the timeroster-server with the "username" and "password" fields as post parameters. The timeroster-server will respond with a html-page, that will be parsed by the webservice-server and depending on it's contents, the webservice will respond to the Android device with either "Success" or "AuthenticationFail".

To do this, I use the SOAP-architecture on my Android Device, which sends a SOAP-enveloppe to the webservice. The webservice then creates HttpWebRequest- and HttpWebResponse-objects that retrieve the html-source from the timeroster-server.

This approach has worked for me so far using the Socket-class and I have been able to login to the timeroster-server, using my android device. However, the problem lies with another function.

My webservice supports 2 functions: "login" and "GetList". I can perfectly call the "login"-function from my android and receive a "Success"-string. But when I call the "GetList"-function (that takes 3 parameters: a username, a password and a listType), it returns a 400 Bad Request.

When I send the exact same http-request to the webservice-server with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), I don't receive a 400 Bad Request error.

Why am I getting a 400 error ONLY when I use my android-device? Is there any way I can fix this?

**Images for visualisation:**

Login-function (using Android):

[image: Login with android]

Login-function (using Fiddler):

[image: Login with fiddler]

GetList-function (using Android) - ERROR HERE:

[image: GetList with android]

GetList-function (using Fiddler):

[image: GetList with fiddler]

**Code used in Android to send data to socket:**

```
public String sendRequest()
{
    String s = "";
    Socket socket = null;
    try
    {
        socket = new Socket(Server, Port);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return "UnknownClientError";
    }
    String stringbuffer = "";
    try
    {
        socket.getOutputStream();
        boolean flag = true;
        PrintWriterSuper printwriter = new PrintWriterSuper(socket.getOutputStream());
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        int i = 295 + MethodName.length() * 2 + XmlNamespace.length();
        for(int j = 0; j < ParamNames.size(); j++)
        {
            String s1 = (String)ParamNames.elementAt(j);
            String s2 = (String)ParamData.elementAt(j);
            i += s1.length();
            i += s2.length();
        }

        printwriter.println("POST " + WebServicePath + " HTTP/1.1");
        printwriter.println("Host: " + Server);
        printwriter.println("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        printwriter.println("Content-Length: " + String.valueOf(i));
        if(!SoapAction.equals(""))
            printwriter.println("SOAPAction: \"" + SoapAction + "\"");
        printwriter.println("Connection: Close");
        printwriter.println();
        printwriter.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
        printwriter.println("<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">");
        printwriter.println("<soap:Body>");
        printwriter.println("<" + MethodName + " xmlns=\"" + XmlNamespace + "\">");
        for(int k = 0; k < ParamNames.size(); k++)
        {
            String s3 = (String)ParamNames.elementAt(k);
            String s5 = (String)ParamData.elementAt(k);
            printwriter.println("<" + s3 + ">" + s5 + "</" + s3 + ">");
        }

        printwriter.println("</" + MethodName + ">");
        printwriter.println("</soap:Body>");
        printwriter.println("</soap:Envelope>");
        printwriter.println();
        boolean flag1 = false;
        int byte0 = 10;
        long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String s4;
        while(scanner.hasNextLine() && !flag1)
        {
            s4 = scanner.nextLine();
            stringbuffer += s4 + "\n";
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - l > (long)(1000 * byte0))
                flag1 = true;
        }
        scanner.close();
        if(!flag1)
        {
            String requestString = printwriter.toString();
            String s6 = MethodName + "Result";
            int i1 = stringbuffer.toString().indexOf("<" + s6 + ">") + s6.length() + 2;
            int j1 = stringbuffer.toString().indexOf("</" + s6 + ">");
            s = stringbuffer.substring(i1, j1);
        } else
        {
            s = "Error: timed out by client";
        }
        try{
        socket.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){}
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        s = e.getMessage() + "\n" + e.getStackTrace().toString();
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: After looking through your code I don't see some serious error or mistake, but I am wondering why you don't use a SOAP library like ksoap2-android? There probably is an error somewhere in the request, maybe just one missing character or one too many.

Comment: Check the encoding, I had a similar issue.

Comment: I'd prefer to keep working with the class I've got now. I'm not a fan of changing too much of the code.

Comment: As for what you said Lunar, what encoding do you mean? The utf-8 in the HTTP-header? Or the encoding used in the inputstream?

Comment: ContentLength 379 is wrong. Its only 13 more then the firstone which had 366. The third parameter takes already more than that. That is a terrible way you calculate the contentlength.

Comment: Yes, I got this class from somewhere online and noticed it as well while I was making adjustments. I'll be fixing that in due time.

Comment: In due time? This is the reason the server gets a bad request!